# trouble comparing strings in wp7 application

Tags: c#, windows, string, windows-phone-7

Here is a sample of my code.

Here I recieve a string variable from another page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string newparameter = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["search"];
        weareusingxml();

        displayResults(newparameter);

    }

private void displayResults(string search)
{
bool flag = false;
try
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("People.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
            List<Person> data = (List<Person>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            List<Result> results = new List<Result>();


            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            {
                string temp1 = data[i].name.ToUpper();
                string temp2 = "*" + search.ToUpper() + "*";
                if (temp1 == temp2)
                {
                    results.Add(new Result() {name = data[i].name, gender = data[i].gender, pronouciation = data[i].pronouciation, definition = data[i].definition, audio = data[i].audio });
                  flag = true; 
                }
            }

            this.listBox.ItemsSource = results;

}
catch
{
    textBlock1.Text = "error loading page";

}
if(!flag)
{
  textBlock1.Text = "no matching results";
}

}
```

Nothing is loaded into the list when the code is run, I just get the message "no matching results".

Comment: Why are you adding the * for temp2 ? Does your Person.Name also contain the * ? Or Are you trying to do a contains search and not an exact match ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to do a contains search (my guess based on your addition of the * around the search string. You can remove the '*' and do a string.Contains match.

Try this.

```
string temp1 = data[i].name.ToUpper();
string temp2 = search.ToUpper()
if (temp1.Contains(temp2))
{
```

Comment: Thank you very much ryadavilli, it worked. The (*) was supposed to be a wild card

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to check if one string contains another (ie substring match) and not if they are equal.

In C#, you do this like this:

```
haystack = "Applejuice box";
needle = "juice";
if (haystack.Contains(needle))
{
     // Match
}
```

Or, in your case (and skip the `*` you added to the string temp2)

```
if (temp1.Contains(temp2))
{
   // add them to the list 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure `data.Count > 0`?